# TensorFlow causes kernel to die on .eval or .run

Tags: tensorflow, kernel

I am running tensorflow code in jupyter on a 2018 MBP with 32g ram.
The code is from Geron's "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow" chapter 9.  Code successfully runs until one point where the code calls .eval or .run at which the kernel dies.

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/09_up_and_running_with_tensorflow.ipynb

The code is contained above.

Cutting and pasting of the above linked code to my own Jupyter notebook and then running results in a kernel death in cell 19:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

reset_graph()

housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape
housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), housing.data]

X = tf.constant(housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
XT = tf.transpose(X)
theta = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.matrix_inverse(tf.matmul(XT, X)), XT), y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    theta_value = theta.eval()
```

and in cell 25:

```
reset_graph()

n_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01

X = tf.constant(scaled_housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0, seed=42), name="theta")
y_pred = tf.matmul(X, theta, name="predictions")

error = y_pred - y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")

gradients = 2/m * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), error)

training_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())
        sess.run(training_op)

    best_theta = theta.eval()
```

To find the problem, I have tried in this last cell to run without mse.eval() and without sess.run(training_op) with success.  That is it does not kill the kernel if that last section is

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =")
```

or if it is:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        print('hi')
    best_theta = theta.eval()
```

but it dies for either of these two:

(1)

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())
```

(2)

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        sess.run(training_op)
```

I have additionally tried this code in Spyder and reinstalled tensorflow.  Same results.  Similar code throughout chapter 9 of Geron's book kills my kernel and I would like to continue as I enjoy his book's instruction.

Comment: it works well for me using TF 1.13. It is hard to understand what is your problem without a detailed error message. Can you lookup the console if there is an error message that shows the reason why the kernel dies ?

Comment: @MoustafaAlzantot.  Thanks for the try. I sorted this.  I reran on a '12 MBP and worked.  I am now rebuilding the '18 MBP in hopes it does the trick.  Really appreciate.